# How to view html in other folder with reveal.js local server

Tags: gruntjs, reveal.js

I'm new to Reveal.js and Grunt, as the doc says, I typed

```
$ grunt serve
```

Then open `http://localhost:8000` and saw that `index.html`. Then I created a subdirectory and add an html into it. I was expecting to see the new html from `http://localhost:8000/subdir/new.html` but failed. Searching through the Internet didn't help.

I think this is a naive question for experienced Reveal.js user. Thank you!

Comment: I just installed Reveal.js and used their sample Gruntfile from here: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/Gruntfile.js  . I was able to create a folder with an index page without issues. It would help if you could post your Gruntfile file and any server.js, app.js or similar in your node app where routes may be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `grunt.initConfig` found [**here**](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)

the qunit is registered to a folder named test :

```
qunit: {
            files: [ 'test/*.html' ]
        },
```

so if you are going to change the sub-directory name , you have to register it before running serve.